# PGFPLOTS: 3d Surface plots using data file

Tags: pgfplots

I want to create 3D surface plot using `pgfplots` in LaTeX. I got the data stored in .csv file, it is available at this link [data.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8c2hm328u6b27m7/data.csv?dl=0)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}   

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\hspace{-1cm}
        \begin{tikzpicture} %
        \begin{axis}[smooth,
        legend pos = north east,
        mark repeat=10,%
        ] %
        \addplot3 [surf,z buffer=sort, mesh/rows=5, shader=interp]
        table[y={batch}, x={index} , z={val_loss}, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
        \end{axis} %
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I got following output

[image]

This is not proper, also in data file number of observations for batch=1,2,4,6,8 is not same. Is that the reason for this messed up plot?
How can I generate the correct surface plot using this type of data.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  I think, you have missed to insert the image of the result?  Also, a lot of people prefer a complete MWE from `\documentclass` till `\end{document}`.  Could you please add both in order helping us to help you.

Comment: Thanks Jan...as per your suggestion I have added the missing data

Comment: Are you sure data.csv is comma delimited?  The link showed formatting.

Comment: yes it is .... Please download data.csv from given link and open in notepad++. I have just checked it.

Comment: I think that you should add the variables that you want to be on the axes and if you want that the colorbar has to be defined according to another set of variables. You also have to explain according to what principle you used `mesh/rows=5` which does not seem to be compatible with the data stored in `data.csv`. Finally, a picture of the desired output would be very appreciated.

Comment: @Pietro, in code variables are listed,    'y={batch}, x={index} , z={val_loss}', batch which is y axis variable, has 5 different values so if you take x and z conditioned on y, it will generate 5 different line plots, using that mesh could be generated as surface plot, I am not sure if my understanding about 'mesh/rows=5' is correct.

Comment: Oh, i see. Your understanding of `mesh/rows=5` is not correct. In fact it has to be interpreted as a hack to read a vector as a matrix (matrices cannot be handled by LaTeX). Hence, if you for example use a 2D square mesh (2 vectors of x and y values) and choose to contour the values according to another axis, `mesh/rows=5` means that every 5 rows pgfplots has to interpret the values of the vector as a new column of the matrix describing the mesh, sonce the x coordinates of the mesh have reached the second boundary and start again from the first boundary. I don't know if it was clear enough.

Comment: Unfortunately the link to the CSV file doesn't work any more. Is it to long to include it directly into the question?

Answer (score 1):

Your data doesn't have to correct format for plotting a surface (the scans in `x` direction have different length).  Use `scatter` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}   

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot3+[only marks,scatter] table[y={batch}, x={index} , z={val_loss}, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]